# Set button target with UIViewController subclass as parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I have `BaseViewController` which is child class of `UIViewController`, then I have this `LeftViewController` and `RightViewController` that are child classes of `BaseViewController`. I want to make a function that creates navbar button items declared from `BaseViewController`, so I can access from the children.

The question is, in order to set the action/selector of each navbaritem, how to pass child view controller as parameter to that function? Some selector are just declared in `LeftViewController` or only declared in `RightViewController`, so the compiler complaint about undeclared selector.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in BaseviewController selector method you can get Childviewcontroller by using the keyword self because there is runtime polymorphism is applied , you can use self as

```
if self.isKindOfClass(RightViewController.classForCoder()) {
    let controller: RightViewController = self as! RightViewController
}
```

Comment: I have already applied your solution, still the compiler complaint about undefined selector, because the parameter itself has type `BaseViewController`.

The code is :
`hamburgerView.addTarget(target, action: #selector(target.doHamburgerAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` has error 

`Value of type BaseViewController has no member doHamburgerAction`.

Even though I know that `target` refers to the correct class.

Comment: show me function decalration of doHamburgerAction function

Comment: `func doHamburgerAction(sender:UIButton) { .. }`

Comment: then do one thing func doHamburgerAction(sender:UIButton) {  } write this function BaseViewController with empty body and overide that function in RightViewController and LeftViewController